# I'm trying add Validation to my two text boxes , but idont know exactly why is not working,when i hit the button! MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm working on project in MVC and I'm trying add Validation to my two text boxes , but idont know exactly why is not working,when i hit the button! and i dont get errors or something.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

The Code in View:

```
@model Produkt


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "OpretProdukt";

}

<h2>Add Product</h2>

<form action="/CMS/Admin/OpretProdukt" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Navn:
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <input type="text" name="Navn" />
               @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Navn)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Beskrivelse::
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="Beskrivelse" />
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Beskrivelse)
            </td>
        </tr>
         <br />
                <input class="KnapStyle" type="submit" value="Opret" />
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>

</form>
```

The Code in Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult OpretProdukt(Produkt p, HttpPostedFileBase Billede)
        {


            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (Billede != null)
                {
                    Uploader uploader = new Uploader();
                    string path = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "/Areas/CMS/Pic/";
                    string file = uploader.UploadImage(Billede, path, 300, true);
                    p.Billede = Path.GetFileName(file);

                    ProduktFac pf = new ProduktFac();
                    pf.Insert(p);
                    TempData["MSG"] = "Opretted";
                }
             else
            {
                TempData["MSG"] = "Fejl ";
            }  

            }
            return RedirectToAction("OpretProdukt");
```

The Code in Models:

```
public class Produkt
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Der skal indtastes et navn")]
        public string Navn { get; set; }
        public int KategoriID { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Der skal indtastes et Beskrivelse")]
        public string Beskrivelse { get; set; }
        public string Billede { get; set; }
        public double Pris { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check below code.As 'Terrance00'said, you have to add the @html.Textboxfor and also to reference the javascript libraries.

```
@model WebApplication15.Models.Test.Produkt

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "OpretProdukt";

    }

    <h2>Add Product</h2>

    <form action="/Home/OpretProdukt" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Navn:
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Navn)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Navn)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Beskrivelse::
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Navn)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Beskrivelse)
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <button type="submit" value="Opret" />
    </form>

    @section Scripts {
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    }
```

Comment: tnx for help :)

Answer (score 1):

Some things that you might have overlooked:

- ASP.NET MVC uses jquery-val and jqueryval-unobtrusive, by default. You need to reference these javascript packages.
- You also need to use the HtmlHelper for the text inputs as this will place the validation attributes into the respective form inputs.

**HtmlHelper**

Instead of:

```
<input type="text" name="Navn" />
```

Place:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Navn)
```

Happy coding - keep asking if you get stuck.

Comment: tnx for help :)